# what does different tags in the below camel-CXF does

Tags: apache-camel

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    ">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

  <!-- Defined the real JAXRS back end service  -->
  <jaxrs:server id="restService"
                address="http://localhost:${CXFTestSupport.port2}/CxfRsRouterTest/rest" 
                staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="customerService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>       
  </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"/>

  <bean id="customerService" class="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService" />

  <!-- Defined the server endpoint to create the cxf-rs consumer -->
  <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:${CXFTestSupport.port1}/CxfRsRouterTest/route"
    serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService" 
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" skipFaultLogging="true">
    <cxf:providers>
       <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsServer>

  <!-- Defined the client endpoint to create the cxf-rs consumer -->
  <cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="http://localhost:${CXFTestSupport.port2}/CxfRsRouterTest/rest"
    serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" skipFaultLogging="true">
    <cxf:providers>
       <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsClient>

  <!-- The camel route context -->
  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
       <!-- Just need to ignoreDeleteMethodMessageBody -->
       <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer"/>
       <to uri="log:body?level=INFO"/>
       <to uri="cxfrs://bean://rsClient?ignoreDeleteMethodMessageBody=true"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>

</beans>
```

In the Camel Docs they say that cxf:rsServer is a REST Consumer where as cxf:rsClient is a REST producer but the code seems to do vice-versa.
Also i want to understand the difference between Jaxrs tag and cxf:rsserver and cxf:rsclient tags.

Answer (score 0):

- jaxrs:server : create a basic endpoint service.
- cxf:rsServer : Is a camel component to create REST endpoint. It will turn a request into a normal Java object.
- cxf:rsClient : Do the opposite of rsServer, it turn a java object to a REST request.

  `<camelContext>
      <route>
          <from uri="cxfrs://bean://rsServer" />
          <to uri="log:body?level=INFO" />
          <to uri="cxfrs://bean://..=true" />
      </route>
  </camelContext>`

If we take a look to the code example, we see that this is a proxy. We received a REST request, we log it and then forward it.

```
 <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:${CXFTestSupport.port1}/CxfRsRouterTest/route"
    serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService" 
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" skipFaultLogging="true">
    <cxf:providers>
       <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsServer>

  <cxf:rsClient id="rsClient" address="http://localhost:${CXFTestSupport.port2}/CxfRsRouterTest/rest"
    serviceClass="org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.testbean.CustomerService"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true" skipFaultLogging="true">
    <cxf:providers>
       <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
  </cxf:rsClient>
```

Theses tags is for configure your cxf component outside from the camel-route.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Thomas that really helped. Just one clarity needed that when you said rsServer converts Request into Java Object did you mean the JSON in the Request is converted into Object?

Comment: Yes, a json or a XML object (With Jaxrs or jackson)